# What does it mean if two culpability factors are combined into one line by a slash in the sentencing guidelines?

Tags: england-and-wales, sentencing

Alicia is convicted of a theft, which was simultaneously highly sophisticated and fully spontaneous (ie involved no planning).

The relevant [sentencing guidelines](https://www.sentencingcouncil.org.uk/offences/magistrates-court/item/theft-general/) provide three separate bands of culpability factors, including:

> Sophisticated nature of offence/significant planning

(Band A factor)

> Other cases that fall between categories A or C because: Factors are present in A and C which balance each other out

(Band B factor)

And:

> Little or no planning

(Band C factor)

If the first of these was instead listed as two separate factors, then the band C factor would seem to balance the former component of the band A factor so as simply to yield a band B offence, while the latter component would be inapplicable and so irrelevant. If, on the other hand, the two components are to be read as exclusive alternatives to each other, and only one or the other may be applicable, then how does the band C factor figure into the equation? Or doesn’t then seem to have a directly corresponding counterpart to “balance”, while the offence seems then to lean more to band A maximum culpability.

Comment: *How* is the theft both spontaneous and highly sophisticated?  Complicated thefts would be hard to devise, let alone pull off, on the spur of the moment.

Comment: Alice and her Polaroid cam realize that security in the museum is lacking and they sell copies of a museum museum piece on site. She buys one, makes an angled photo to pin against the camera, swaps the original for the copy and then just walks out.

Comment: @Mary Alicia is an expert safe cracker but useless at picking locks. She walks past an office every day and sees a safe through the window, knowing that if she could ever get in the building she would probably have a fun challenge at cracking the safe inside but files the idea well away because it’s just an imaginary scenario anyway as she knows it would be impossible for her to get inside. One day she walks past and sees that the door had been left ajar, or perhaps the window had been smashed by a previous burglar, so she goes inside and  has at the safe with her expert skills

Comment: Actually okay so that’s a burglary not a theft. But imagine a similar scenario perhaps with something that’s not in a building.

Comment: @Trish Anyway I think I just at least partially understood by realising that you probably meant pinning against a security camera of the museum rather than the aforementioned Polaroid camera. But what is an “angled photo”?

Comment: A photo that approximates the look from the security camera's angle,  as in, fooling someone looking on the screen that nothing goes on while A makes the swap

Comment: Right, I thought it might be something like that. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @Seekinganswers  You describe a complicated plan, not at all spontaneous.

Comment: @Mary okay, suppose that Harry the hacker is a professional penetration tester who is able to do very sophisticated exploits wirelessly to undermine security systems, if only he can see join the wifi network that they run on. On his way home from work, he happens to notice that Victor his serendipitous victim has happened to leave the main base station of the network on the kitchen table upside down near the window so that the passwords are legible from outside after Victor was trying to change the batteries before realising that he didn’t have the type of screwdriver that would have been

Comment: …needed for the job. He seizes on this opportunity, even though there had been no prior planning or preparation to exploit the vulnerability as he was just walking home on his way back from work when he noticed and promptly seized on tut. He then remotely connects to the wireless camera system, disarms it, and deletes all of the so far collected footage, before making off with Victor’s decorative statues that sit in front of his doors. The heist was indeed sophisticated and yet it was also fully spontaneous and not at all planned in advance. In fact, Victor upon seeing the opportunity was so

Comment: …confident in his own skills that he didn’t even envision how all of the steps of the heist would go but just knew that he would able to figure it out as he went along just as soon as he walked past, saw the make of the camera system that was in use as one that he knew his way around very well, and noticed that the Wi-Fi password and configuration interface credentials had been carelessly left exposed on the table.

Comment: @Seekinganswers  No one would believe him when he claimed he didn't plan it.